# How to use 1 Intent to transport between activities?

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm using Xamarin to develop android programs.
My app has many different activities which they pass data to each other by using for example this code:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(ViewAccountActivity));
myIntent.PutExtra("loginedcustomer", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(loginedCustomer));
StartActivity(myIntent);
```

and then retrieve this data by

```
loginedCustomer = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Customer>(Intent.GetStringExtra("loginedcustomer"));
```

now my question is that for every transition to another activity i have to make intent and put the data and start it which means that i have to retrieve the data and then put it again and start my new intent.
is there any easier way to do this?
like using one intent and only change where it is headed?(in the constructor)
thank you

Comment: If you need to use the same object across many activities, why don't you put that object in [Application class](http://www.intridea.com/blog/2011/5/24/how-to-use-application-object-of-android)? and later on, retrieve from that only?

Comment: pass either Messenger or ResultReceiver via Intent's extras

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Application class for accessing same object across many activities.

```
public class TestApplication extends Application {

    public TempClass tempClass;

    public TestApplication () {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() { 
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();
    }

    public TempClass getTempClass() {
        return tempClass;
    }

    public void setTempClass(TempClass tempClass) {
        this.tempClass  = tempClass;
    }
}
```

Now in your Activity:

```
//after setContentView
testAppObj = (TestApplication) getApplication();
testAppObj.setTempClass(myTempClassObj);

//retrieve as:
TempClass obj = testAppObj.getTempClass();
```

Hope this helps.

P.S:
You must register your Application class in your manifest file just like you register your activities:

```
<application
        android:name="com.pkg.test.TestApplication " />
```

Comment: is the data in this method will be removed when the application get closed? or can i save them on file?

Comment: They will be removed. If you want to save simple string, you can try [Shared preference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) @saeedek

Comment: thank you.but do you know how to apply this to xamarin(c#)? there is an application object which when i try to cast to my custom class gives me an error saying that cannot cast

Comment: @saeedek no idea about xamarin(C#).. :(