# How to pass arguments activity to activity

Tags: android, cookies

I am trying to make Login Authentication in the Android project.I want to pass the cookie from activity to activity.To pass cookie , I have created an application class.Here is the application class;

```
public class TestApplication extends Application{

    public Cookie tempClass;

    public TestApplication () {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() { 
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();
    }

    public Cookie getTempClass() {
        return tempClass;
    }

    public void setTempClass(Cookie tempClass) {
        this.tempClass  = tempClass;
    }
```

}

and I am trying to use in the activity here ;

```
public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub          
                        //String sessionId="";
                        Cookie userCookie=null;
                        List<Cookie> cookies = ((AbstractHttpClient) httpClient).getCookieStore().getCookies();
                         if (cookies.isEmpty()) {
                                System.out.println("None");
                            } else {
                                for (int i = 0; i < cookies.size(); i++) {
                                    //System.out.println("-Cokkkiiieee " + cookies.get(i).toString());
                                    userCookie =cookies.get(i);
                                }
                                testAppObj = (TestApplication)getApplication();
                                testAppObj.setTempClass(userCookie);
                                Intent menu = new Intent("android.intent.action.MENU");
                                startActivity(menu);
                            }
                    }


             };
                (new Thread(runnable)).start();
```

LogCat is shown :

```
 FATAL EXCEPTİON : Thread-9
 java.lang.ClassCastException : android.app.Application
 at com.example.example.MainActivity$2.run(MainActivity.java:176)
 at java.lang.Thread.Run(Thread.java:1096)
```

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5575072/1777090)? else you can also use Application class to keep cookies. So you can access them across activities.

Comment: are there any way to pass this cookie between activities except Bundle?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25665595/1777090). You can save cookies like that and retrieve from application class later.

Comment: I have tried the application class method but  testAppObj = (TestApplication)getApplication(); is giving classCastException?what might be cause of this?

Comment: Did you extend Application class in TestApplication? Please update question with logcat and code.

Comment: I have edited post , ı am sorry it took some time.I extended grom the Application class.Should ı add to androidManifest.xml this application.

Comment: What's `testAppObj` in your code?

Comment: Global , TestApplication

Comment: I can't post image of LogCat because of my reputation

Comment: I have solved.I must be added into androidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Application class for accessing same object across many activities.

```
public class TestApplication extends Application {

    //Object declaration

    public TestApplication () {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() { 
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();
    }

    //setter getter for object
}
```

**Now in your Activity:**

```
//after setContentView
TestApplication testAppObj = (TestApplication) getApplication();
testAppObj.setSomeObj(myObj);

//retrieve as:
someObj = testAppObj.getterMethodOfObj();
```

Hope this helps.

P.S:

You must register your Application class in your manifest file just like you register your activities:

```
<application
        android:name="com.pkg.test.TestApplication " />
```